# Problem in output regarding insertion at end of circular linked list

Tags: c

This is my code for insertion in the end of a circular linked list for which I am getting correct result

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *head;

void insert(int val)
{
    struct node *temp;
    struct node *tail;

    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = val;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
        temp->next = head;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
        tail->next = head;
    }
}

void printlist()
{
    struct node *temp = head;
    printf("The elements of the linked list area \n ");
    while (temp->next != head)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("%d ", temp->data);
    printf("%d", temp->next->data);
}
int main()
{
    int n, i, val;
        printf("Enter how many elements in a circular likedlist you want \n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    head = NULL;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            // printf("Enter the value\n");
            // scanf("%d,&val");
    
    insert(i);
   
        }
    printlist();
}
```

for which the output is

```
Enter how many elements in a circular likedlist you want 
10
The elements of the linked list area 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
```

However, for the same code when I try to take values from the user it gives me incorrect output.here in this code I just changed a part of the `main` function inside the for loop where I am taking input for the `val` instead of passing an integer in function `insert`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *head;

void insert(int val)
{
    struct node *temp;
    struct node *tail;

    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = val;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
        temp->next = head;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
        tail->next = head;
    }
}

void printlist()
{
    struct node *temp = head;
    printf("The elements of the linked list area \n ");
    while (temp->next != head)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("%d ", temp->data);
    printf("%d", temp->next->data);
}
int main()
{
    int n, i, val;
        printf("Enter how many elements in a circular likedlist you want \n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    head = NULL;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("Enter the value\n");
            scanf("%d,&val");
    
    insert(val);
   
        }
    printlist();
}
```

For this program, the output I am getting is

```
Enter how many elements in a circular likedlist you want 
5
Enter the value
1
The elements of the linked list area 
 0 0
```

Can anyone suggest me where my code is going wrong?

Comment: Do you compile with `gcc` or `clang`? If so, add the compiler options `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and then rerun your top program. Not even that is working reliably and if you run it when compiled with those options, it'll tell you where something bad happens.

Comment: `tail` is uninitialized in the `else` branch.

Comment: `scanf("%d,&val");`  --->  `scanf("%d", &val);`

Comment: How is it "circular"?

Comment: @EugeneSh.  The last element's next pointer points to head.

Comment: @AllanWind But there is zero benefit in it. When a new element is inserted, a new node is created. Circular lists make sense when they have fixed capacity. Also it is supposed to maintain some kind of a pointer to current "head"/"tail".

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's a different question.  We don't know why op choose a circular list.

Comment: @AllanWind Well, maybe it is just referring to the general structure of the list, while I am thinking of circular buffer...

Comment: A circular list has no endpoint.  If it has an endpoint, it is not circular.

Answer (score 1):

Symptoms: "It worked, then it didn't." This is the hallmark of UB. Your compiler didn't output code that affected the stack between iterative calls in your first example. The bytes used for `tail` during each invocation were not overwritten. In the second example ("user input"), `scanf()` has made use of the same region of stack (as it should), and the *fortunate* behaviour of the first example became *unfortunate*. This is why "It worked, then it didn't." Undefined behaviour has many guises...

If you want to be respected as a coder, you don't use global variables, and then compound the mistake with adding more globals. Or 'scanning' what could be millions of nodes to find the tail of a LL.

The code below declares an ordinary node, and a special *header* node that are compatible.

The testing in `main()` uses two LLs; one for some integer values, and one that grows with only the odd numbered integer values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

typedef struct {
    int data;     // NB: same name & order of 1st two struct members
    node_t *next; // (ditto)
    node_t *tail; // head knows where its backend is
    int cnt; // meta-information becomes simple to implement
    int id;
} head_t;

head_t *append( head_t *ph, int val ) {
    static int take_a_number = 0;
    node_t *nn = (node_t *)calloc( 1, ph ? sizeof(node_t) : sizeof(head_t) );
    /* omitting check */

    nn->data = val;
    nn->next = nn; // for now, a 'ringlet'

    if( ph == NULL ) {
        ph = (head_t*)nn; // notice the casting of compatible struct entities
        ph->tail = nn;
        ph->id = ++take_a_number;
    } else {
        nn->next = (node_t*)ph;
        ph->tail = ph->tail->next = nn;
    }
    ph->cnt++;

    // debug traversal showing results
    printf( "list #%d - %d nodes: ", ph->id, ph->cnt );
    node_t *p = (node_t*)ph;
    do
        printf( "%d ", p->data );
    while( (p = p->next) != (node_t*)ph );
    puts( "" );

    return ph;
}

int main() {
    int i;

    // two lists. Could be 100, or an array of them...
    head_t *p1 = NULL, *p2 = NULL;
    for( i = 7; i <= 49; i += 7 ) { // just some arbitrary data
        p1 = append( p1, i );
        if( i%2 )
            p2 = append( p2, i );
    }

    printf( "Two laps around first list: " );
    node_t *pFun = (node_t*)p1;
    for( i = 2*p1->cnt + 1; i; i-- )
        printf( "%d ", pFun->data ), pFun = pFun->next;
    puts( "" );

    /* omitting `free()` of heap */

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
list #1 - 1 nodes: 7
list #2 - 1 nodes: 7
list #1 - 2 nodes: 7 14
list #1 - 3 nodes: 7 14 21
list #2 - 2 nodes: 7 21
list #1 - 4 nodes: 7 14 21 28
list #1 - 5 nodes: 7 14 21 28 35
list #2 - 3 nodes: 7 21 35
list #1 - 6 nodes: 7 14 21 28 35 42
list #1 - 7 nodes: 7 14 21 28 35 42 49
list #2 - 4 nodes: 7 21 35 49
Two laps around first list: 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 7
```

**0** *global variables*, and traversing the LL is only done when printing. This is part of *structured programming*.

Comment: The message is right, but the delivery of it feels a little hostile.

Comment: @Chris You wouldn't believe the burns I've suffered when suggesting ANYTHING BUT "_best practice_"... Now I cop it for my tone when I've taken the time to give the OP advice better than competing answers... Can't win sometimes... `:-)` (Yes, recommending **more** global variables, or **scanning** what could be a mile-long LL deserve to be criticised, imho.)

Comment: If you're planning to start an answer with _"If you want to be respected as a coder"_ you should be careful as it will get nitpicked. Consider that you've cast the result of `malloc` which is generally discouraged in C.

Comment: @Chris _Most_ SO answers **discourage** using global variables (as is right.) **Both** competing answer ___recommend___ another global variable (with a tone of "I don't believe I am typing this..") Why the preoccupation with this answer. Some get correcting comments, some get DVs... Because both competing answers (at this time) recommend another global variable, I'm left wondering why they have NO DVs (given how long they've been 'up'.) Perhaps I should edit MY answer to begin, "Use a global variable for `tail`... or..." // sarcasm off (casting malloc return required by old sys. nitpicking!)

Comment: That's a good example worthy of a nod. May be worth adding a `print_list()` function showing how to iterate over a circular list. With a `head`, `tail` pointer it is less vexing on new circular-linked-list learners than without. But you would be surprised how mysterious iterating correctly can be. (especially for the circular list where you should be able to iterate the complete list from any node, not just `head`,)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for the nod `:-)`. The guts of `printLL()` is shown in the `// debug...` block. As _stand-alone_ function has been left as _an exercise for the reader_ `:-)`... The "two circuits of the track" show how the 'one to the next' are unaffected by going past the _head_ node (as if it were an ordinary node). If I wrote about the special handling for the head node deleting a node, I'd want an address to send the invoice to... `:-)` Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: I can't speak for others, but I don't generally DV for poor practices but rather typically for outright wrong answers or non-answers.

Comment: @Chris And, for answers that answer/address the OP's issue with "best practice" code examples? This is becoming a "chat" (to be avoided.) (It still astounds me how fast and furious "flaming" happens here on SO, and how reluctant people are to UV or accept answers... Human nature, eh?)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Just coming back to this. Yes, this is a _peculiar_ circular LL in that one node is _special_ (like the clasp on a necklace)... Armed with easily maintained meta-data `cnt`, a function could iterate to find a _node-of-interest_, then do a full circuit (or as many nodes as desired) from that start location by counting down toward 0. `:-)` If the 'head' affected access times, transforming a 'head' to a 'regular', and a 'regular' to a 'head' could be done without breaking the bank... `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is probably to make `tail` a global variable like `head`.  I also refactored `insert()` to reduce duplication, added error checking for `malloc()` and `scanf()`, tweaked `printlist()` to not print the head twice:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *head;
struct node *tail;

void insert(int val) {
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    if(!temp) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    temp->data = val;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = temp;
    } else {
        tail->next = temp;
    }
    tail = temp;
    tail->next = head;
}

void printlist() {
    printf("The elements of the linked list area \n ");
    for(struct node *temp = head; temp; ) {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
        if(temp == head) break;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter how many elements in a circular likedlist you want \n");
    int n;
    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    head = NULL;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        insert(i);
    }
    printlist();
}
```

and it the output is now:

```
The elements of the linked list area 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

You could eliminate the head pointer (`tail->next == head`) if you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the `insert` function, the `else` branch is dereferencing pointer variable `tail` that has not been initialized. (The variable `tail` has *automatic* storage class, i.e. it is a "stack" variable, so it's value is not preserved between calls to the function.) The `tail` variable needs to point to the last element on the list.

The function can be changed to search for the last element of the list like this:

```
void insert(int val)
{
    struct node *temp;
    struct node *tail;

    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = val;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        /* find last element */
        for (tail = head; tail->next != head; tail = tail->next)
            ;
        tail->next = temp;
    }
    temp->next = head;
}
```

(However, it probably makes more sense to store the `tail` statically outside the function as in Allan Wind's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73790320/5264491) so that the function does not have to waste time finding the last element of the list each time it is called. It should also check for memory allocation failure, as in that answer.)

---

The `printList` function does not currently work if the list is empty. It will dereference `head` even if it is `NULL`, leading to *undefined behavior*. That can be fixed by moving the all code that accesses the elements of the list inside a `if (head != NULL) {` `}` block:

```
void printlist(void)
{
    struct node *temp = head;
    printf("The elements of the linked list are \n ");
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        while (temp->next != head)
        {
            printf("%d ", temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        printf("%d", temp->next->data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```